# How to solve equation sets with SymPy to find some angles?

Tags: python, numpy, math, sympy

I do not quite understand how to solve my equation set with SymPy in Python. I have tried using `solve()` and `nsolve()`. `solve()` gives me no answer, it just stands and goes, `nsolve()` gives me this error.

`ValueError: Could not find root within given tolerance. (7378.8100001153525709 > 2.16840434497100886801e-19) Try another starting point or tweak arguments.`

This is what I have written when I tried using `solve()`:

```
from sympy import *

theta_1, theta_2, theta_3 = symbols('theta_1 theta_2 theta_3')

eq1 = -136.2*sin(theta_2)*sin(theta_3)*cos(theta_1) + 136.2*cos(theta_1)*cos(theta_2)*cos(theta_3) + 222.1*cos(theta_1)*cos(theta_2)

eq2 = -136.2*sin(theta_1)*sin(theta_2)*cos(theta_3) + 136.2*sin(theta_1)*cos(theta_2)*cos(theta_3) + 222.1*sin(theta_1)*cos(theta_2)

eq3 =  136.2*sin(theta_2)*cos(theta_3)+ 222.1*sin(theta_2) + 136.2*sin(theta_3)*cos(theta_2) + 100.9 

eq1 = Eq(eq1, 0)
eq2 = Eq(eq2, (-323.90))
eq3 = Eq(eq3, 176.71)

ans = solve((eq1, eq2, eq3), (theta_1, theta_2, theta_3))

print(ans)
```

This is what I have written when I tried using `nsolve()`:

```
from sympy import *

theta_1, theta_2, theta_3 = symbols('theta_1 theta_2 theta_3')

eq1 = -136.2*sin(theta_2)*sin(theta_3)*cos(theta_1) + 136.2*cos(theta_1)*cos(theta_2)*cos(theta_3) + 222.1*cos(theta_1)*cos(theta_2)

eq2 = -136.2*sin(theta_1)*sin(theta_2)*cos(theta_3) + 136.2*sin(theta_1)*cos(theta_2)*cos(theta_3) + 222.1*sin(theta_1)*cos(theta_2)

eq3 =  136.2*sin(theta_2)*cos(theta_3)+ 222.1*sin(theta_2) + 136.2*sin(theta_3)*cos(theta_2) + 100.9 

ans = nsolve((eq1, eq2, eq3), (theta_1, theta_2, theta_3), (0, -323.9, 176.71))

print(ans)
```

I want to find an expression for theta1, theta2, and theta3. Preferably in the form of arctan2. Does anyone know how I can do this? or why this does not work?

Comment: Are you sure there is a solution?

Comment: Yes, I did the calculations by hand and found expressions for theta1, theta2 and theta3. The onely difference is that i used variables instead of of the numbers 136.2, 222.1 and 100.9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm presuming that your inputs are supposed to be angles in degrees. Here `nsolve` can give you an answer if you give the inputs in radians:

```
In [48]: p = (pi/180).evalf()

In [49]: nsolve((eq1, eq2, eq3), (theta_1, theta_2, theta_3), (0, -323.9*p, 176.71*p))
Out[49]: 
⎡-1.5707963267949 ⎤
⎢                 ⎥
⎢-9.36640725122338⎥
⎢                 ⎥
⎣-2.49008907692194⎦
```

We can reduce your system to a system of polynomials with rational coefficients like this:

```
In [60]: c1, c2, c3, s1, s2, s3 = symbols('c1:4 s1:4')
    ...: rep = {cos(theta_1): c1, cos(theta_2): c2, cos(theta_3): c3,
    ...:        sin(theta_1): s1, sin(theta_2): s2, sin(theta_3): s3}
    ...: 
    ...: eqs = [eq.subs(rep) for eq in [eq1, eq2, eq3]] + [
    ...:         c1**2 + s1**2 - 1, c2**2 + s2**2 - 1, c3**2 + s3**2 - 1]
    ...: eqs = [nsimplify(eq) for eq in eqs]

In [61]: for eq in eqs:
    ...:     print(eq)
    ...: 
Eq(681*c1*c2*c3/5 - 681*c1*s2*s3/5 + 2221*c1/10, 0)
Eq(681*c2*c3*s1/5 - 681*c3*s1*s2/5 + 2221*s1/10, -3239/10)
Eq(681*c2*s3/5 + 681*c3*s2/5 + 2221*s2/10 + 1009/10, 17671/100)
c1**2 + s1**2 - 1
c2**2 + s2**2 - 1
c3**2 + s3**2 - 1
```

From there you can use SymPy's `groebner` function to compute a Groebner basis for the solution of the polynomial system. For symmetry we will add a separating element t:

```
In [62]: gb = groebner(eqs, order='grevlex').fglm('lex')
```

This is like a new list of separated equations whose solutions are the cos and sin values for the different thetas that you wanted.

The final equation is a polynomial of degree 20 in `c3` and its solutions can be substituted into the other equations to give the full solution of the system. The polynomial has 4 real roots each of which is a root of a smaller irreducible polynomial of degree 8. Due to Abel-Ruffini there cannot be radical expressions for the roots but it is possible to compute them numerically:

```
In [70]: c3num = [r.n() for r in real_roots(gb[-1])]

In [71]: c3num
Out[71]: [-0.795172954862362, -0.552080421425289, 0.702791508766261, 0.99923774387104]
```

Each of those can be used to solve the rest of the Groebner basis:

```
In [73]: for c3n in c3num:
     ...:     for eq in gb[:-1]:
     ...:         print(solve([eq.subs(c3, c3n)], dict=True))
     ...:     print(solve([c3 - c3n], dict=True))
     ...:     print()
     ...: 
[{s1: -1.00000000000000}]
[{s2: -0.0583375690202956}]
[{s3: -0.606382694211788}]
[{c1: 0}]
[{c1: 0.0}]
[{c2: -0.998296913792728}]
[{c3: -0.795172954862362}]

[{s1: -1.00000000000000}]
[{s2: 0.881316344165583}]
[{s3: 0.833790866034178}]
[{c1: 0}]
[{c1: 0.0}]
[{c2: -0.472526720395763}]
[{c3: -0.552080421425289}]

[{s1: -1.00000000000000}]
[{s2: -0.0656752871541357}]
[{s3: 0.711395878031908}]
[{c1: 0}]
[{c1: 0.0}]
[{c2: 0.997841047763359}]
[{c3: 0.702791508766261}]

[{s1: -1.00000000000000}]
[{s2: 0.226102985521720}]
[{s3: -0.0390375619754195}]
[{c1: -3.05175781250000e-5}, {c1: 3.05175781250000e-5}]
[{c1: 0.0}]
[{c2: 0.974103403161280}]
[{c3: 0.999237743871040}]
```

The last case appears to be numerically inconsistent but this might be rounding errors because this is quite numerically unstable and perhaps the solution should be c1=0. I think this happens because your equations are a slightly degenerate case.

The above gives all solutions for the cos and sin of your angles and you can use `atan2` to get from there to the angles themselves. You can use `nsolve` to refine any of the above as accurately as you want. The first of the 4 cases is the one found by `nsolve` above.

If you wanted an explicit analytic expression here then it seems unlikely.

Comment: I just saw that I had forgotten to write cos(theta_2) at the end of eq1 and eq2. I have changed to the correct expression in the question now. sorry

Comment: You've misunderstood the arguments to `nsolve`. If you ask to solve for the theta1, theta2, theta3 then the numbers that you provide are  initial estimates for those variables not the right hand sides of the equations.

Comment: ahh, it makes sense thanks for the help. But if I can not use nsolve, what should I use then?

Comment: At the top of this answer I showed that nsolve does work for the equations you showed. You just need to make sure that you are passing in the right equations and giving a reasonable initial estimate for the solution.

Comment: ok, then i will try that.  Thanks for all the help!!